# Angular patchValue vs setValue and dates

Tags: angular, forms, date, momentjs, angular-reactive-forms

Is there any significant difference between using patchValue or setValue to set the value on a form ?
Also is there any difference or best practice regarding using moment or date obj ?

```
     if(startDate) {
        const date = moment(startDate).toDate();
        this.form?.patchValue({ startDate: date });
      }

      if(endDate) {
        const date = new Date(endDate);
        this.form.get('endDate').setValue(date);
      }
```

Either way it works as expected for me , so I am just wondering .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment is a matter of preference, you don't NEED it but you can sure use it.

As for patch VS set, the difference is mainly on form groups rather than form controls : setValue requires all fields to be set, but patchValue accepts a partial of all the fields that are expected.

Answer (score 0):

we use patchValue if we need to update a single value in object or complete object, but we use setvalue when we have to update the object and not single value.